# Need to disable copy/paste command on excel 2007 across different users

Tags: excel, vba, macros, copy, paste

I need to disable the copy/paste in excel 2007. The excel file will be sent to different users so i need a solution where copy/paste is disabled for all users.
I have searched the web but everyone has asked to enable the macros but the problem with that is i will have to enable the macros for every user first before restricting them from copy/pasting.
So looking for a solution where i can write some vba code on sheet to restrict all users from copy/pasting without enabling macros.

Thanks.

Comment: "where i can write some vba code on sheet to restrict all users from copy/pasting without enabling macros" - that would be a neat trick...

Comment: Locking the Sheet using a password isn't an option?

Comment: @BennoGrimm No that won't work.. I Want to restrict the users from copy/pasting.. the sheet is already protected but still users can copy/paste.. Vba code is what i need.. i would really appreciate that..

Comment: _where i can write some vba code ... without enabling macros_ macros is just another name for VBA, so what you are asking for is impossible

Comment: Have you looked at the [ribbonx] tag? There are ways to disable icons per workbook just when they are active.  Disabling the icon also disables shortcut keys too.

Answer (score 0):

Lock the Cells [with the Protection Option of Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-cells-in-a-worksheet-b2f833bd-9db5-48a4-9ec0-8e451ac27c3a) manually or [lock them programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff836172.aspx).

Example:

```
'Range Lock
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G37").Locked = True
'Sheet Lock
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect
```

EDIT:
 Just saw ur new comment, there is no option to use VBA code to block ONLY copy/pasting without allowing Macros in ur Workbook.

Comment: I dont want to protect the complete sheet.. there are few cells that should be editable.. but copy paste feature should be blocked for all cells..

Comment: Without allowing VBA Code/Macro's that is not possible hence why Tim Williams left a sarcastic comment and why i edited the post a while ago.

When u allow Macro's tho the Programmatically version i linked can protect cells individually

Comment: Is it possible to keep the macros disabled and through some VBA code block the copy/paste feature.?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this.

1. Go to the review tab
2. Select protect sheet
3. Protect with password and take away the ✓ (there should only be one)

Comment: But that would protect the complete sheet i still want some columns editable. But copy/paste feature on all cells should be blocked.

Comment: I don't think it is possible then. You can block the cells you don't need to edit and don't allow the user to touch them, but i really don't think that there's a way to just unable copy-paste.